# AttributeError: module 'sqlalchemy' has no attribute 'Binary'

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am getting error `AttributeError: module 'sqlalchemy' has no attribute 'Binary'` when trying to use SQLAlchemy library in Python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sqlalchemy.Binary` was renamed to `sqlalchemy.LargeBinary` and deprecated in 0.6 and finally removed in [version 1.4](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/changelog_14.html). Use library version < 1.4 or upgrade the codebase.

Comment: Actually, `Binary` was "renamed" to `LargeBinary` in version 0.6 — about 11 years ago — with the old name retained (emitting a deprecation warning) until version 1.4 finally removed it.

Comment: Thank you Gord. I edited the answer and clarified this.

Comment: Flask-SQLAlchemy==1.3.* (from versions: 0.5, 0.6, 0.9, 0.9.1, 0.10, 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 1.0, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 3.0.0a1, 3.0.0a2, 3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3, 3.0.4, 3.0.5) there is no version 1.4

Comment: `Flask-SQLAlchemy` is Flask wrapper fot `SQLAlchemy` and a different package.